# MySQL SELECT Blank Field

Tags: mysql

I'm having some trouble with retrieving some records from my database. Many of the pages that are on my site are tagged with various values to aid in searching/organization. One of these values was set up with a checkbox. If the box is checked in the backend the value is "1". If it has not been checked it's blank.

Here is my `SELECT` statement. It is used in an AJAX search for site visitors to search for products.

```
SELECT *,
MAX( CASE WHEN name = "is_active" THEN value END ) AS is_active,
GROUP_CONCAT(...
...
HAVING is_active LIKE "%'.$active.'%"
```

I've omitted a portion of my `SELECT` statement to conserve space.

The statement works perfectly except for the example I gave. If the visitor doesn't check the active checkbox on the front end it returns results as if it was checked...or equal to "1". There is no change if the box is checked. It seems like I can't get it to return the records where `is_active` is equal to "". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as though the field in your database has the default value as `NULL`. You can add a second condition in your `HAVING` clause to check for this:

```
HAVING is_active LIKE "%' . $active . '%" OR is_active IS NULL
```

EDIT

I just saw you define `is_active` in the select list. With `MAX()`, the empty values will be ignored. You can use a nested-`CASE` to fix this:

```
SELECT *,
MAX(
    CASE WHEN name = "is_active" THEN
        (CASE WHEN value IS NULL THEN 0 WHEN value = '' THEN 0 ELSE value END)
    END
) AS is_active
...
```

Answer (score 1):

So if `$active` is blank, then your query looks like:

```
is_active LIKE "%%"
```

This will return all rows where that column is not `NULL`. Is there a reason you need to search using the wildcards? Perhaps you just need:

```
is_active = "'. $active .'"
```

[Here is an example that illustrates my point.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/41b78/3)